# Magento 1.9 Coupon code applied but subtotal, grand total and withdiscount totals not updating in quotes/carts

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, quote, discount, coupon

I m facing strange issue as follows:

I have created one **shopping cart rule** - with 10% on every product and to all customer groups.

**Conditions** and **Actions** applied for all the products.

When i add product to the cart/quote, an entry has been added to the **quote**  as per below:

Coupon_Code - SAMPLEFIRST10

TOTAL - $100.00

SUBTOTAL - $100.00

SUBTOTAL_WITHDISCOUNT - $100.00

GRANDTOTAL_WITHDISCOUNT - $100.00

So totals are not updating after applied discounts.

Checked few things so far such as tax module, rewrite promo cart rules, done reindex multiple times, no conflict found for promo cart rules but still no luck found.

Comment: Did you get what you want @sandip

Comment: @Gem - yes it is resolved. it was some XML update which needs to add. Thanks

Comment: Can I get more details?